# Different result of a Double Variable inside Switch Case and outside switch in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%
String amount2="0";
amount2=request.getParameter("amount");
// out.println(amount2);
// Double amount1=0.00;
Double amount1=Double.parseDouble(amount2);
out.println("\n Double amount is = "+amount1);
Double result=0.0;
String currency=request.getParameter("source");
int ch=Integer.parseInt(currency);
out.println("\n selection value is "+ch);
switch(ch)
{
case 1 :
                 {
                     out.println("In GBP");
              result=amount1*100.70;  
out.println(result);                      
   }
         case 2 :
                             {
                                 result=amount1*0.59;
         }
                     case 3 :
                                 {
                              result=amount1*0.043;                           
                     }
                                             case 4 :
      {
                                                                                                      result=amount1*56.64;
                                             }
                                                  case 5 :
                                                  {
                                                      result=amount1*54.91;
                                                  }
                                                             case 6:
                                                         {
                                                          result=amount1*60.17;                                                                              
                                                             }
                                                               case 7:
          {
                                                                                result=amount1*52.15;                                                               
                                                               }
    }
```

out.println(result);
      %>
When i Try to print the value of the result variable it shows two different results.The value printed inside the switch case is correct but when i print it outside switch then it changes. i want to know why it is happening. Is it a problem with my IDE or something else ? HElP !!

Comment: Please format your code. It is unreadable.

Comment: its because u have not put break; statement after each case block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `break;` after each of your `case`s.

```
case 1:
{
    out.println("In GBP");
    result=amount1*100.70;
    out.println(result);
    break;
}
case 2:
{
    result=amount1*0.59;
    break;
}
case 3:
{
    result=amount1*0.043;
    break;
}
case 4:
{
    result=amount1*56.64;
    break;
}
case 5:
{
    result=amount1*54.91;
    break;
}
case 6:
{
    result=amount1*60.17;
    break;
}
case 7:
{
    result=amount1*52.15;
    break;
}
```

Otherwise program flow will continue and all cases below the matching case will be executed.

Comment: Thanks , i totally forgot it. Silly mistake it was :/ . Thanks for helping.. :) (Y)